# How to remove path from linked library in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

I generated one library which contains following libraries :

command used :

> g++ -o testmylibrary -Xlinker -R
>   /med/build/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/linux32/gcc-6.2.0/lib -ggdb3 -m32
>   -fno-tree-vectorize file1.o fileMain.o mylibrary.so -lm -lstdc++ -lsupc++

```
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7bc4000)

libstdc++.so.6 => /med/build/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/linux32/gcc-6.2.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7a4b000)

libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7a22000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /med/build/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/linux32/gcc-6.2.0/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7a07000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf78ac000)  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00796000)
```

i want to remove path "`/med/build/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/linux32/gcc-6.2.0`" from **libstdc++** and **libgcc_s** libraries.

what option to give g++ to remove these path and make them same as **libpthread**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is a run-time linker search path, and it is not encoded into the filenames of the shared libraries. `-R` linker option embeds that path into `RPATH` entry of the object being produced. Check that with `readelf -d testmylibrary`.

The run-time linker searches for required shared libraries first in directories mentioned in `RPATH` entries and then in the standard locations. It happens that `/med/build/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/linux32/gcc-6.2.0/lib` contains those libraries, so that the dynamic linker uses them.

If you remove `-R /med/build/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/linux32/gcc-6.2.0/lib` option, that path is not going to be used by the run-time linker when searching for the required shared libraries.

You also do not need to link explicitly to `-lstdc++` and `-lsupc++`, `g++` does that for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This explains my problem very well. :)